# Put Multiple Datasources into a Single Source

Tags: sql, database, database-design, etl, data-warehouse

Assume I have a list of contaminated sites in NY with the primary key ContamID The list has records ranging from **1990 to 2004**.

Table 1:

- ContamID
- CauseOfContamination
- Address
- State
- ZipeCode

Now lets assume after few months we got an updated list for the year **1990 to 2011** with the given columns

Table 2:

- CID (as same as ContamID)
- Cause_Contam
- Address_1
- Address_2
- State
- ZipeCode
- Long
- Lat

Within weeks we got another updated list for the year 2011 to 2014 with the given columns:

Table 3:

- SiteID (Totally different PK than table 1 and 2)
- Site Address
- Site County
- Site Zipcode
- LevelOfRisk

All the three tables represent list of contaminated sites. However, those tables came in different structure every time there was an update. How can I come with a good solution that is easily maintainable, consistent, and won't require extensive data analysis for every update?

I thought to create a dimensional table that will hold the three keys:

- ContamID
- CID
- SiteID

This is a problem I have been facing lately and trying to find a sustainable consistent solution.

However, the problem is some records of ContamID and CID overlap with each other. Surely CID has to supersede ContamID as CID represents the updated record. Alternatively, I could merge Table 1 and Table 2.

You might have a better approach to such a problem. Any advise will surely help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a "master data management" (MDM) task.  There are many packages out there to help with this.  Basically, they come down to defining synonyms or inferrences which are applied at ETL time e.g. "John Smith" = "Smith, John" = "J. Smith".

Design *your* database for *your* needs and let MDM and ETL deal with the translation from source systems.